# Blurry fonts after upgrading to 10.04, Nvidia issue?

Tags: nvidia, 10.04, fonts, display-resolution

Recently I upgraded from 8.04 LTS to 10.04.

The previous version had some problems regarding screen settings. X only recognised 1024x768 as resolution of my monitor, mainly because the monitor was not identified correctly.

With 10.04 the monitor and its resolutions are identified correctly and the system chooses a better resolution.

But now the fonts seem blurry. They are hard to read. I tried a larger font size which improves the situation a bit. I also played around with `nvidia-settings`. If I choose 1024x768 again, the fonts look good. 
Also some resolutions with specific refresh rates seem better. Another thing I tried was to change hinting settings. However the best variant was already chosen.

So I've run out of ideas for a solution. Do you have any hints?

My graphics card is nVidia Corporation C68 GeForce 7050 PV / nForce 630a (rev a2).

Comment: Post more information about your monitor: is it a CRT or an LCD?

Comment: Is it all fonts, or just some?

Comment: It is a CRT monitor. All I can tell is that the manufacturer is Medion, a german based hardware company. I have no manual or something for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with my installation in the last few days. What seemed to help was uninstall all nvidia stuff, remove the old `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reinstall nvidia again. I'll have to go through this old `xorg.conf`. Maybe there was some strange setting.

I could manage to start the Nouveau driver, but there was no real improvement regarding font settings. The only drawback it had, was the missing 3d acceleration. Thatswhy I went back to nvidia binaries. However in a few weeks I'll try nouveau again. Maybe it has improved in some way.

Answer (score 8):

You might be using wrong settings for subpixel hinting - it might be turned on when it shouldn't be, depending on your monitor. I've found that 10.04 defaults to having it turned on with LCD panels (haven't tested a CRT in a while.)

Your panel might be also returning the wrong information about the color order.

Check the Appearance settings. `nvidia-settings` may override the Free Software stack - there's a lot of points where nvidia driver does odd things. Try temporarily removing the `nvidia` driver to let `nouveau` drive the hardware and see if the situation improves.

As of note `nouveau` in Ubuntu 10.04 does not have 3D acceleration, but is quite fine in 2D.

Comment: I tried it, but nouveau sets the screen resolution to 800x600 (or 640x480). ATM I'm trying to find a way to fix this.

Comment: Restarting gdm was not enough. When I restarted the whole system the resolution was correct, but the blurry fonts stayed.

Comment: Now that you're trying nouveae, see Marcelo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that in 8.04 all vertical lines in fonts are drawn sharply, but in following releases, vertical lines in fonts are blurred a little. It may or may not be the problem you're having, but it's worth looking at. [This blog post](http://johan.kiviniemi.name/blag/ubuntu-fonts/) explains how to revert the setting.

Comment: The original author of the blog article had a LCD monitor. I'm using a CRT. When I tried his suggestion the situation got a bit worse. So I went back to my defaults.

Comment: Darn. Well, it was worth a shot. I hope you find the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the font rendering options.

Start with...

```
System > Preferences > Appearance > Fonts > Details
```

... and play with the smoothing and hinting options. I know I played a while until I felt the fonts were well rendered.